# Page Setup in Aspose PPT/Slides

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-slides

I am using aspose-slides-17.3-jdk16.jar for java. I want to customize the page setup for slides in PPT.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have observed your requirements for setting the slide size using Aspose.Slides. I like to mention that slide size is set on presentation level, so we have got a single slide size for entire presentation. Please try using following sample code for getting and setting different slide size properties using Aspose.Slides.

```
Presentation pres=new Presentation("Test.pptx");
//Getting Orientation
//SlideOrienation 0: Landscape 1: Portrait
int orientation=pres.getSlideSize().getOrientation();

//Setting orientation
pres.getSlideSize().setOrientation(SlideOrienation.Portrait);

//Setting Slide size
// Method SetSize is used for set slide size with scale content to ensure fit
pres.getSlideSize().setSize(720, 540, SlideSizeScaleType.EnsureFit);

// Method SetSize is used for set slide size with maximize size of content
pres.getSlideSize().setSize(SlideSizeType.A4Paper, SlideSizeScaleType.Maximize);

//Getting SlideSizeType: Read only property
int SizeType= pres.getSlideSize().getType();

//Getting slide Size: Read only property
Dimension2D slideSize=pres.getSlideSize().getSize();
```

Please also visit, [SlideOrienation](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/slides/com.aspose.slides/SlideOrienation) and [SlideSizeType](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/slides/com.aspose.slides/SlideSizeType) enumeration for your further kind reference. I also like to add further here that in Aspose.Slides we have 72 pixels per inch for slide size. So a normal slide with 10''x 7.5'' will have corresponding size in Aspose.Slides as 10*72 x 7.5*72= 720 x 540.

If there still an issue, you are more than welcome.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.